# PACF correct interpretation

Tags: time-series, python

I'm three days old to Time Series Analysis and I'm trying to build an AR model on the variable slope_ma, which is a one period difference of X's mva 5 periods. X is generated from a random walk process.

$\Large Z_t = slope_{ma_t} = MVA(X;5;t) - MVA(X;5;t-1)$

$\Large Z_{t} = \Phi_{1}Z_{t-1} + \Phi_{2}Z_{t-2} + \Phi_{2}Z_{t-3} + \Phi_{4}Z_{t-4} + \Phi_{5}Z_{t-5} + \Phi_{6}Z_{t-6}$

(Ref. Time Series Analysis - Univariate and Multivariate - Second Edition - William Wei, pg. 15)

In this case k=0

As I understand PACF at lag $t-6$ (, $\approx 0.3.945$), corresponds to the value of $\Phi_{k6}$ coefficient and as per my knowledge that means that term $t-6$ it is positively correlated with term $t-1$ and $t$ itself.

But something tells me I'm wrong, cannot be that easy.

Can some one please explain correct interpretation for this case?

The code below performs the following analysis:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots as sgt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA

class RandomWalk:

    @staticmethod
    def gen_random_walk(size, std, last_date=None, value_0=0, freq="H", output_col_name="X"):

        if last_date == None:
            _last_date = datetime.today()
        else:
            _last_date = parser.parse(last_date)

        _p_t = np.zeros(size)
        _wn = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=std, size=size)
        _p_t[0] = value_0
        _wn[0] = 0

        _date_index = pd.date_range(end = _last_date, periods=size, freq=freq)

        _df_rw = pd.DataFrame(np.stack([_p_t, _wn], axis=1), columns=[output_col_name, "wn"], index=_date_index)

        for i in range(1, size):
            _df_rw.iloc[i][output_col_name] = _df_rw.iloc[i - 1][output_col_name] + _df_rw.iloc[i].wn

        return _df_rw

PRD = 5
df = RandomWalk.gen_random_walk(10000,0.0001,value_0=1.0,freq="5min")
df["X"].plot(figsize=(15,5), title="X")
plt.show()
df["mva"] = df["X"].rolling(PRD).mean()
df["slope_ma"] = df["mva"] - df["mva"].shift(1)
df["slope_ma"].plot(figsize=(15,5), title="Slope MA")
df.dropna(inplace=True)
sgt.plot_pacf(df.slope_ma, lags=40, zero=True)
plt.show()

model = ARMA(df.slope_ma, order=(6,0))
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PACF at lag $6$ mean the correlation de $X_t$ and $X_{t-6}$ that does not take into account the intermediate terms ($X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, X_{t-3}, X_{t-4}$ and $X_{t-5}$)

Comment: Correct, and now I also know that the pattern in PACF (spikes each 5 periods) is because is detecting a Moving Average process in the underlying data, which is the case; Z is a one period difference on a 5 periods moving average.